# material css button cutting off icons

Tags: css, angularjs, materialize

im using materialize css with angularjs... my button icons are getting cut off, i tried the materialize icons and font-awesome icons, same result.

[screenshot of buttons with icons moved downward and cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCwev.jpg)

```
<nav class="red darken-4">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href ng-click="navToCPQ()"><img class="ml-3" src="../../assets/content/images/logo.png" /></a>
        <div class="right pr-3">
            <a href class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-2"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></a>
            <a href class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-2"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="pr-3 right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href ng-click="navToCPQ()">CPQ</a></li>
            <li><a href ng-click="navToPC()">Process Control</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you share a link to the page?

Comment: add some related  CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your CSS. Without seeing your actual code we can only guess what the exact problem is and what may be the ideal solution.

However, since images are cut off, you can set the `height` of the container, so it will be bigger and there will be place for `image`s. You could also check the size of the `image` tags and the size of the `image` files and compare them. Also, you can move the `image`s upwards using the `background-position-y` property or the anchors using the `margin-top` CSS property.